# Haskell Types vs. Typeclasses in architecture

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have an application whose core data are Projects, Document Sets ("DocSets"), and Documents ("Docs"). Docs are not restricted to any particular content-type; they could be spreadsheets, images, HTML, etc., and can have functions/behaviors other documents don't have. Similarly, I might have multiple kinds of DocSets depending on the type of behavior I need. Maybe this DocSet presents the documents in a flat list, maybe that one associates a status with each document, and has some cool rendering trick based off of status.

The code might look like this if I wasn't using typeclasses:

```
data Project = Project {
  projName :: Text,
  projDocSets :: [DocSet]
}

data DocSet = DocSet {
  dsName :: Text,
  dsDocs :: [Doc]
}

data Doc = Doc {
  docTitle :: Text,
  docType :: Text,
  docContents :: ByteString
}
```

The problem I see with this is while it allows there to be multiple kinds of Docs (via the docType field), it essentially uses manual type checking, which doesn't feel right (in my head). I could have data constructors for PagedTextDoc, ContinuousTextDoc, SpreadsheetDoc, ImageDoc, etc. That seems like poor modularity to me.

> **EDIT:** My "poor modularity" comment relies on knowledge that wasn't communicated very well. Each Doc has some common behaviors
>   ((de-)serialization, being grouped into a DocSet, a title, rendering,
>   others as the application evolves), and some unique behaviors
>   (internal representation in an easy-to-edit format, saving incremental
>   edits, partial rendering to HTML assuming application is a web app).
>
> Even if that weren't the case, it seems to me like the app would be
>   more modular if I could just create a new module, define my document
>   and what you can do with it, and bang, document is now supported. That
>   way, I define my paginated document over here, my spreadsheet over
>   there, and the two don't care about each other at all.

Maybe I could use a typeclass for Docs?

```
data DocSet = DocSet {
  dsName :: Text,
  dsDocs :: [Doc]
}

class Doc d where
  docTitle :: d -> Text
  docType :: d -> Text
  docContents :: d -> ByteString
```

The declaration for dsDocs now doesn't typecheck; lists only work for one particular concrete type, vs. any member of a typeclass. The DocSet definitely needs to be able to store/reference multiple kinds of documents.

I've tried to do some searching, but frankly, my Google skills completely fail here. Am I thinking about the data structures correctly? Is the approach with all of (Proj, DocSet, Doc) as a single data constructor each really the best way of handling this, or am I missing something about the way Haskell handles polymorphism?

Comment: What is wrong with the first approach? Change `docType :: Text` to `docType :: DocumentType` and it seems perfectly sensible. In which way is having an enumeration for your document type poor modularity?

Comment: Also, if you look at type classes as modelling "something", then any type class of the form `class C x where f0 :: x -> T0; f1 :: x -> T1; .. fn :: x -> Tn` is simply modelling a record with field `{ f0 :: T0, .. , fn :: Tn }`. So your class formulating gives you no more power than your record type formulation (and as you can see, is actually harder to work with).

Comment: Edited in an attempt to clarify, but I probably didn't do that well. Your suggestion would work great if this application was going to be a viewer. I might need to add editing later, dunno what the timeline for this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose I have an application whose core data are Projects, Document
>   Sets ("DocSets"), and Documents ("Docs"). Docs are not restricted to
>   any particular content-type; they could be spreadsheets, images, HTML,
>   etc., and can have functions/behaviors other documents don't have.

It sounds like you don't know that types can have multiple constructors (sum types). Instead of your `Doc` do:

```
data Doc = PagedTextDoc {docTitle :: Text, docContents :: ByteString}
         | SpreadsheetDoc {docTitle :: Text, docContents :: ByteString}
       ... etc
```

> Similarly, I might have multiple kinds of DocSets depending on the
>   type of behavior I need. Maybe this DocSet presents the documents in a
>   flat list, maybe that one associates a status with each document, and
>   has some cool rendering trick based off of status.

```
data DocSet = ListDocset Text [Doc] | KoolDocset [(Status, Doc)] | ...etc
```

Comment: I actually knew about that functionality, but in the context of, say, Binary Trees. Change the way docContents is presented with each data constructor, and I think that's an interesting way of thinking about it.

Comment: This breaks the modularity I was looking for, but it is clean, and does what I need it to. Would that there was a way to split different kinds of docs out into different modules.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the class-based proposal doesn't even work.  Classes aren't types.  You can't have `[Doc]` if `Doc` is a class.

The usual approach here is to determine what it is you're modeling, exactly.

Do you want a bunch of things that behave uniformly, and can easily be packaged up together?  Then put that behavior into a type.  This is usually done by creating a record that holds a function for each kind of behavior you want.

On the other hand, do you have a bunch of things that require very different handling?  In that case, put the data into a bunch of types and let the type checker (and exhaustiveness checker) guide you along the way to make sure you're always handling the right thing in the right place.

I don't recommend using classes for this at all. Classes are (mostly) good only for the situation where you can write type-polymorphic code that is meaningful when there is a concrete type, but you don't need to know what the type is. (This is a slight exaggeration, but it's close enough to the truth to use it as a first-approximation heuristic.)

Comment: Great thoughts. See if the clarification changes anything at all for you.